# Swift: Set GameScene variable from GameViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I need to pass on several variables from my GameViewController to my GameScene.

GameViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size) as GameScene? {

        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false
        skView.showsPhysics = false

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        // pass game set-up variables
        scene.idDefence = idDefence
        scene.idAttack = idAttack
        scene.tries = tries
        scene.runs = runs
        scene.teamShirt = teamShirt

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

GameScene - has the variables listed above (idDefence) etc.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    // variables - set-up defenders
    var idDefence = 0
    ...
```

This complies but the idDefence variable, which println as a number correctly from GameViewController, isn't passed to the active GameScene and remains as 0. The GameScene code:

```
override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)

    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    getDefenceInfo()
    getAttackInfo()

    loadLevel()
    spawnPlayers()
    spawnDefenders()

}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


// get attack variables from database
func getDefenceInfo(){
println("defence ID: \(idDefence)")
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Where in `GameScene` are you checking the value of the properties?

Comment: In a function 'getDefenceInfo()' which is called from 'override init(size; CGSize)' - I will edit my initial question to show this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking the value of those properties in the `init(size:)` initialiser; which is called on the line:

```
if let scene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size) as? GameScene {
    ... 
}
```

At this point, the code that sets the value of the properties, from GameViewController, hasn't been run; therefore they still have their default value.

If you check the value of the properties in the `didMoveToView` method of your `GameScene` you'll see they all have thier correct value, since `didMoveToView` will be called after `skView.presentScene(scene)`.